# do routers route packets between two private subnets internally?

Tags: networking

i'm a beginner to networking and would like some clarification on this:
suppose you have two private subnets (private IPs on both) on the same router from the inside (ie IT department subnet and Accounting department subnet), does the router route packets between these two internal private subnets or are the subnets isolated from one another and no communication can occur?

thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private IP addresses are private because the community agreed that these are not to be routed on the public Internet. For a router there is no difference between these "private" IP addresses and "public" IP addresses; for a router they are both the same.

Thus to answer your question, yes, the router will route packets between these two internal networks. And that's another thing, a router doesn't know anything about "internal" or "external" networks. These are terms used in firewalls to differentiate between less and more secure regions.

Comment: Though routing doesn't really have concepts like internal and external, there are some asymmetries which could be interpreted as such. First of all whether you have a /0 route and which interface it will use. But also whether you are delegating prefixes, receiving delegated prefixes, and sending router advertisements and on which interfaces you are doing those things.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you're trying to say. What does assymetric routing have to do with public/private or internal/external addresses or the original question?

Comment: I wasn't commenting on the question. I was commenting on you saying: a router doesn't know anything about "internal" or "external" networks. And I wasn't saying anything about asymmetric routing, I was pointing out that interfaces on a router are not all configured equal.

Comment: Okay, please enlighten me then. How does a router know about internal vs external interfaces? How are its interfaces not all equal?

Comment: Routers for end user networks typically have a designated WAN interface which by default will run a DHCP client and receive router advertisements. They will also have one or more LAN interfaces on which they will typically run a DHCP server and send router advertisements. On backbone routers you will configure interfaces differently depending on whether they are connected to: another of your own routers, a customer, a peer, an upstream provider.

Comment: "Routers" for end users have integrated switches, hence the difference between internal and external interfaces. Backbone routers have different configurations depending on what device they connect to, true, but that doesn't make the router interfaces any different. E.g. running BGP for an internal peer, a customer or an upstream provider changes the BGP configuration and its function, but the router interface just keeps on routing IP packets.